# bootstrap switch not working

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [bootstrap switch](http://bootstrapswitch.com/) and I installed it with Nuget package manager. This is what my solution explorer looks like after the installation:

[image: bootstrap-switch.css]

[image: bootstrap-switch.js]

Then I add two new bundles for them in my BundleConfig.cs:
[image: bundle]

I used the bundle in my layout view like this:
[image]

In the actual view, I have a checkbox like this:
[image]

I also initialize the bootstrap switch in the document ready function:
[image]

but when I run the page, it still looks like I didn't include the css file correctly:
[image]

Comment: Please See in browser console - See error ?

Comment: Check developer console for errors, check if the input box output has the right name attribute.

Comment: @AsifRaza Hmm, I used microsoft edge, it says "Syntax error bootstrap-switch.css(22, 1)", when I open the css file, I saw a green line under "user-select: none", is that the issue?

Comment: @Null please see my above comments

Comment: It's mean that js framework not found. If you can make it to jsfiddle or sniper code we can fix it clearly for you

Comment: You are rendering CSS files for Bootstrap Switch as JS files because you have provided `@Scripts.Render("~/Content/BootstrapSwitch")` at your layout page. You need to change it to `@Styles.Render("~/Content/BootstrapSwitch")`

Comment: @mmushtaq You are absolutely right !